# Qual é o critério para respostas que apontam para respostas do próprio autor?

Tags: debate, perguntas, respostas

No STO em ingles vejo várias respostas (aceitas) em que quem responde apresenta uma explicação sucinta e aponta para um texto ou para uma outra resposta. [Aqui eu tentei fazer algo precido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214808/7412), a diferença é que aponto para uma resposta que eu mesmo elaborei, e tive um voto negativo. Minha duvida é: Qual seria o procedimento mais adequado? Repetir o texto da resposta original? Não responder e apenas comentar? Fiquei em dúvida.

Comment: De fato aqui a cultura é de "exigir" respostas um pouco mais elaboradas. Nesse ponto eu acho que somos melhores. Tem que discorde. Acho que aqui somos menos fórum. Até costuma haver sinalização quando só contém um *link* e em muitos casos eu transformo em comentário. Esta eu não sei se seria o caso se fosse sinalizado. Mas se a resposta é a mesma, então ocorre que a pergunta provavelmente é duplicata e no lugar de responder poderia sinalizar para que ela fosse fechada. Se não é duplicata então dê uma resposta diferente. Digo diferente mesmo, não só disfarçar. Só não fechei porque entendo pouco

Comment: No caso a pergunta em si não é exatamente "duplicata" mas a resposta atende as duas, pergunta (tl;dr) Eu mesmo poderia sinalizar como "possível duplicata"? Se for o caso vou deletar a resposta e fazer isso.

Comment: Se a resposta atende as duas, é a definição de duplicata. Você pode sinalizar e quando tiver mais reputação poderá votar.

Comment: Ok, vou deletar a resposta e colocar o link nos comentarios, certo?

Comment: Se acredita ser duplicata: em baixo de cada pergunta existe o link chamado **Sinalizar**, clique nele e selecione a opção `Deveria ser fechada ...` > `Duplicada de ...` e cole o link da pergunta o qual tem a resposta que resolve o problema.